# Does io.BufferedReader actually support readline?

Tags: python, io, python-3.6

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/io.html#io.BufferedReader) `io.BufferedReader` inherits `io.IOBase`: `io.IOBase` -> `io.BufferedIOBase` -> `io.BufferedReader`. Consequently, it is supposed to implement `readline` and `readinto`, but it doesn't seem to be the case, because I get an `AttributeError`. A minimal example:

Data sample:

```
$ printf 'foo bar\nspam ham\n' | gzip -c > compressed_file.gz
```

Test code:

```
import gzip
import io

with io.BufferedReader(gzip.open('compressed_file.gz', 'rt')) as buffer:
    buffer.readline()
```

Exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-215a0d9b4feb> in <module>()
      3 
      4 with io.BufferedReader(gzip.open('compressed_file.gz', 'rt')) as buffer:
----> 5     buffer.readline()

AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'readinto'
```

Am I missing something?

**Update**

The funny thing is that you can manually get an `io.TextIOWrapper` out of `io.BufferedReader` wrapping a byte stream and the `readline` method will work.

```
import gzip
import io

with io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedReader(gzip.open('compressed_file.gz'))) as buffer:
    buffer.readline()
```

Seems like `_io.TextIOWrapper` instances returned by `io.BufferedReader` are not the same as `io.TextIOWrapper` instances, though the latter [is directly imported from `_io`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1426daa4fe47d8f8be0d416f7cba7adae1d5839f/Lib/io.py#L57).

Comment: Why did you choose to open in text mode? `[t] ->` text, `b ->`binary

Comment: @MosesKoledoye because I'm passing the handle into a 3-rd party function, that wants a TextIO instance.

Comment: Does the code in the Update section now solve your issue?

Comment: @JanneKarila technically speaking, it does (in the sense that the error goes away), but it works slower than unbuffered `gzip.open(..., 'rt')`. In Python 2, the buffering solution used to work well as a remedy for Python's appallingly slow `gzip` implementation, but no more.

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are indeed missing a critical detail: [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedReader) wraps around an existing [`RawIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase) object:

> *class io.BufferedReader(raw, buffer_size=DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)*
>
> A buffer providing higher-level access to a readable, sequential `RawIOBase` object.

And because you've opened your gzip file in **text** mode, it is not a `RawIOBase` instance:

```
>>> f = gzip.open('compressed_file.gz', 'rt')
>>> isinstance(f, io.RawIOBase)
False
```

In other words, this is a user error.

If you wrap a `BufferedReader` around a **binary** file you'll see that the `readline` method works just fine:

```
>>> io.BufferedReader(io.BytesIO(b'foo\nbar')).readline()
b'foo\n'
```

Comment: The problem is, the whole thing works fine without a `BufferedReader` wrapper. That is `gzip.open(..., 'rt')` returns a handle with a properly implemented `readline`.  Hence, if `BufferedReader` is supposed to return a wrapper around the underlying buffer, then this is not a user error.

Comment: BTW: `io.TextIOWrapper` inherits `io.TextIOBase`, which in its turn inherits `io.IOBase` (the base class defining `readline` and `readinto`). Considering that `RawIOBase` itself inherits `io.IOBase`, there should be no difference between subclasses of  `RawIOBase` and  `io.IOBase` with respect to the `readline` protocol. Thus, there should either be another explanation or this is a good case for a documentation patch.

Comment: I've updated the question. Seems like the `_io.TextIOWrapper` returned by  `BufferedReader` is not the same as `io.TextIOWrapper`, although the `io` module directly imports `TextIOWrapper` from the C-extension `_io`.